# checkbox for multiple level headers in Jquery Grid Multigrouping

Tags: jqgrid, checkbox, grouping

I am using jquery grid version 4.4.1 . I have used **multiselect: true** option to enable the checkboxes for all the rows. I am also using 2 level grouping i.e grouping by 2 fields. But i am not getting the checkboxes for those grouping headers. only my actual records are getting checkboxes. Please help me to know if there is any way we can use it.

Comment: You should show some code. It is way more easy to help you if we can see the problems.

Comment: grouping: true,
 groupingView : {
 groupField : ['moduleName', 'subModuleName'],
 groupColumnShow : [false, false],
 groupText : ["<b>{0} </b>","<b>{0} </b>"],
 groupCollapse : true, 
 groupOrder: ['asc', 'asc'],
                                                                 The groupText : field needs checkboxes to select all the records under particular group. But multiselect: true does not display checkboxes for that. Please help me with that

Comment: Please use the edit button and add the code to your question. You can format it as code and improve readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<code> grouping: true,
 groupingView : { groupField : ['moduleName', 'subModuleName'],
 groupColumnShow : [false, false], 
 groupText : ["<b>{0} </b>","<b>{0} </b>"],
 groupCollapse : true, 
 groupOrder: ['asc', 'asc'], 
 The groupText : field 
</code>
```